# ArcGIS Interpolation IDW and Spline, extreme values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted, spline

I am trying to interpolate air pollution data that is displayed in 1x1 Km points in ArcGIS. I am having two issues:

1. When I try to interpolate using IDW, the software freezes at 94% "building search tree," and I have had not been able to produce an IDW surface
2. When I try to interpolate using the spline method, a raster is executed but with extreme negative (-91) and positive (82) values that are not within my data range (0-17)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.